# Show that the following vectors in the space of real valued functions are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the vectors {sin(2x),cos(2x),sin(x)cos(x)} in the space of real valued functions defined on [0,2π] are linearly dependent.

So I know in order to show that the vectors are linearly dependent I need to show that the vectors are a linear combination. So I want to find a non-zero solution to c$_1$sin(2x)+c$_2$cos(2x)+c$_3$sin(x)cos(x)=0 but how do I go about this? do I u just plug in random values for x?

Answer (score 0):

using the trigonometry identity:

$sin(2x)=2sin(x)cos(x)$

shows that immediately.

Comment: so then I would have 2c$_$1sin(x)cos(x)+c$_2$cos(2x)+c$_3$sin(x)cos(x)=0 but how does that help me show they are linearly dependent?

Comment: take: $c_1=1, c_2=0$ and $c_3=-2$, then you will have: 

$sin(2x) - 2sin(x)cos(x) = 2sin(x)cos(x) - 2sin(x)cos(x) = 0$ for all x, i.e. this gives the function that is zero-constant which is the zero vector in our space.

Comment: you need to show that you can get the zero function as a linear combination of these 3 functions... so, you need to find $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$ s.t. for all $x \in [0, {\pi}/2]$ you have: $c_1 \sin(2x) + c_2 \cos(2x) + c_3\ sin(x)cos(x)=0$